# Navigation drawer only from ActionBar?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-4.4-kitkat

I have the following problem. I noticed that on Android 4.4.2 (and possibly all 4.4.x) the `NavigationDrawer` does not work exactly as in lower version. It works fine, when opened via click in the `ActionBar` icon. But when I tried to open it by swiping from the side around the middle of the screen, only small grey area comes in instead of my `NavigationDrawer`. It looks like [this](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2zj9xts&s=5#.Uqnkk-Lvc3k).

I also noticed, that I am not the only one who has this kind of problems, as both Evernote and Duolingo suffers from the same problem. Is there anyway to make the drawer open correctly by swiping from the side ?

I added the Drawer exactly the way described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Edit : When I drag from the top left corner, everything is fine, but when I drag from the left edge somewhere in middle of the screen, something weird shows instead of a drawer. See the first link for the screenshot.

Comment: If you drag from the center, it's not enough to make the drawer snap. You have to start dragging from the (left) edge of the screen.

Comment: "as both Evernote and Duolingo suffers from the same problem" -- I cannot reproduce your problem with the Evernote app. Hence, I recommend that you edit your question to explain precisely how you are getting this effect and to add screenshots illustrating what the effect is.

Comment: Edited the question, tried to be more clear, screenshot already there.

Comment: Do you have any code that might take any events from being send to the drawer? Do you use any ViewDragHelper?

Comment: It could be that some app you have installed uses the left edge as a hotspot for it's own purposes (ex. opening a global sidebar). There are many apps out there that does exactly that and they override certain areas for all apps.

Comment: Well this might be it. Some app I have installed is probably causing this. When I restarted the phone, the problem is gone. Well thank you for the comments, now I will try to figure out which app is to be blamed.